# Angular i18n select: translate some values, use others as is

Tags: angular, internationalization

I'm using i18n in an angular 7 project like so:

```
 <a *ngIf="!last" [routerLink]="[item.url]" i18n="Breadcrumbs@@breadcrumb-label"> {item.label, select, projects {Projekte} new {Neu}}</a>
```

This works fine so far. Lower level breadcrumbs display a name attribute which will not be translated. How do i translate item.label when it is e.g. project or new and leave it as is if it isn't?

I tried

```
 {item.label, select, projects {Projekte} new {Neu} other {item.label}}
```

and

```
 {item.label, select, projects {Projekte} new {Neu} other item.label}
```

but obviously neither of them worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using seperate templates:

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="isFixedLabel(item.label) ? fixed : other; context: { item: item }"></ng-container>

<ng-template #fixed i18n="Breadcrumbs@@breadcrumb-label" let-item="item"> {item.label, select, projects {Projekte} new {Neu}}</ng-template>
<ng-template #other let-item="item">{{ item.label }}</ng-template>
```